# UI not updating with NotifyPropetyChanged for datatable

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous, async-await, task

I have two datatables "ResultData" and "OutputData".  One of these receives results from an sql query, the other I am manually adding rows to.

ResultData gets the results from a query updates the UI appropriately. However OutputData does not.  I'm going to link the entire method below.  I've been stuck on this for a while, it seems to be caused due to it being async but I'm not sure how to fix it.  Here is the constructor and method

```
class SqlInterfaceViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private IDBQuery connection;
    private string sql;
    private DataTable resultData;
    private DataTable outputData;
    public ButtonViewModel Bvm;
    private string resultStatus;
    private bool queryRunning;
    private string elapsedTime;
    private int sqlCount;

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public SqlInterfaceViewModel(IDBQuery connection)
    {
        this.connection = connection;
        outputData = new DataTable();
        outputData.Columns.Add("DateTime", typeof(string));
        outputData.Columns.Add("Action", typeof(string));
        outputData.Columns.Add("Message", typeof(string));
        outputData.Columns.Add("Duration", typeof(string));

        Bvm = new ButtonViewModel(new ButtonModel(new Action(executeSql)));
        OutputData.RowChanged += new DataRowChangeEventHandler(Row_Changed);


    }
    public bool QueryRunning
    {
        get { return queryRunning; }
        set
        {
            if (value != this.queryRunning)
            {
                queryRunning = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("QueryRunning");
            }
        }
    }
    public string Sql
    {
        get { return sql; }
        set
        {
            if (sql != value)
                sql = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Sql");
        }
    }
    public DataTable ResultData
    {
        get { return resultData; }
        set
        {
            if (resultData != value)
                resultData = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("ResultData");
        }
    }

    public DataTable OutputData
    {
        get { return outputData; }
        set
        {
            if (outputData != value)
                outputData = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("OutputData");
        }
    }

    public string ResultStatus
    {
        get { return resultStatus; }
        set
        {
            if (resultStatus != value)
                resultStatus = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("ResultStatus");
        }
    }
    private  void Row_Changed(object sender, DataRowChangeEventArgs e)
    {
        OnPropertyChanged("OutputData");
    }

    private List<string> sqlList(string sql)
    {
        List<string> SqlList = sql.Split(';').ToList();
        return SqlList;
    }

    public async void executeSql()
    {
        foreach (string statement in sqlList(sql))
        {
            QueryRunning = true;
            System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch sw = new System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch();
            DateTime dateTime = DateTime.Now;
            try
            {
                sw.Start();
                if (statement.ToUpper().Contains("SELECT"))
                    ResultData = await connection.GetResultSetTask(statement);
                else
                    sqlCount = await connection.ExecuteUpdate(statement);
                sw.Stop();
                elapsedTime = sw.Elapsed.ToString(@"hh\:mm\:ss\.ffff");

                if (statement.ToUpper().Contains("SELECT"))
                    OutputData.Rows.Add(dateTime.ToString(), statement, ResultData.Rows.Count.ToString() + " rows selected", elapsedTime);
                else if (statement.ToUpper().Contains("UPDATE"))
                    OutputData.Rows.Add(dateTime.ToString(), statement, sqlCount.ToString() + " rows updated successfully", elapsedTime);
                else if (statement.ToUpper().Contains("INSERT"))
                    OutputData.Rows.Add(dateTime.ToString(), statement, sqlCount.ToString() + " rows inserted successfully", elapsedTime);
                else if (statement.ToUpper().Contains("DELETE"))
                    OutputData.Rows.Add(dateTime.ToString(), statement, sqlCount.ToString() + " rows deleted successfully", elapsedTime);
                else
                    OutputData.Rows.Add(dateTime.ToString(), statement, sqlCount.ToString() + " records affected", elapsedTime);

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                OutputData.Rows.Add(dateTime.ToString(), sql, sqlCount.ToString() + " records affected", elapsedTime);
            }
            finally
            {
                QueryRunning = false;
            }
        }
    }

    public void OnPropertyChanged(string propName)
    {
        if (this.PropertyChanged != null)
            this.PropertyChanged(
                this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propName));
    }
}
```

I have double checked my DataTable properties as well as the binding in the xaml and both are setup the same.

The executeSql method is being called via ICommand

```
    public class ButtonViewModel {
    private bool canExecute;
    private ICommand clickCommand;
    private ButtonModel model;

    public ICommand ClickCommand { get { return clickCommand ?? (clickCommand = new CommandHandler(() => ClickAction(), canExecute)); } }
    public string ImageUriString { get { return UriStringFactory.GetUriString(model.ImageUriString); } }
    public string HoverText { get { return model.HoverOverText; } }

    public ButtonViewModel(ButtonModel model) {
        canExecute = true;
        this.model = model;
    }

    public void ClickAction() {
        model.CommandAction();
    }
}

internal class CommandHandler : ICommand {
    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;

    private readonly Action action;
    private readonly bool canExecute;

    public CommandHandler(Action action, bool canExecute) {
        this.action = action;
        this.canExecute = canExecute;
    }

    public bool CanExecute(object parameter) {
        return canExecute;
    }

    public async void Execute(object parameter) {
        await Task.Run(action);
    }
}
```

Comment: I presume this is firing from an event?  Can you show the event declaration and how you call `executeSql()`?

Comment: Also is it possible your update/insert statements contains the text "select"; e.g. "insert dbo.table1(column1) select 42"?

Comment: It should be noted, that if I click on one of the column headers, the datagrid does update at that point... I have added the constructor for my class as well as the buttonviewmodel.

Comment: @sellotape yes, it is entirely possible which would cause incorrect ouput potentially..  but for the sake of testing this issue, im just running "Select * from table"

Comment: you need to show us more of `SqlInterfaceViewModel`, specifically you need to show us the class definition and the implementation of the `Row_Changed` method. Also `CommandHandler.canExecute` has no way to be updated after you create the command, changing the value of `ButtonViewModel.canExecute` does not change the value in the `CommandHandler`.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain I have updated my post to include the entire class.  QueryRunning and ResultData both update with notifypropertychanged, but the OutputData does not refresh in the datagrid that is bout to it until clicking on a column header or resizing the form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the issue by using Application.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke

ill post my solution below

```
    class SqlInterfaceViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    private IDBQuery connection;
    private string sql;
    private DataTable resultData;
    private DataTable outputData;
    private string resultStatus;
    private bool queryRunning;
    private string elapsedTime;
    private int sqlCount;
    private string selectedText;
    private bool cancelSql;

    public ICommand CommandExecute { get { return new ButtonViewModel(new ButtonModel(new Action(executeSql))).ClickCommand; } }
    public ICommand CommandCancel { get { return new ButtonViewModel(new ButtonModel(new Action(Cancel))).ClickCommand; } }
    public ICommand CommandClear { get { return new ButtonViewModel(new ButtonModel(new Action(Clear))).ClickCommand; } }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public SqlInterfaceViewModel(IDBQuery connection){
        this.connection = connection;

        outputData = new DataTable();
        outputData.Columns.Add("DateTime", typeof(string));
        outputData.Columns.Add("Action", typeof(string));
        outputData.Columns.Add("Message", typeof(string));
        outputData.Columns.Add("Duration", typeof(string));
        cancelSql = false;

        OutputData.RowChanged += new DataRowChangeEventHandler(Row_Changed);
    }
    #region public properties
    public bool QueryRunning
    {
        get { return queryRunning; }
        set
        {
            if (value != this.queryRunning)
            {
                queryRunning = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("QueryRunning");
            }
        }
    }
    public string Sql
    {
        get { return sql; }
        set
        {
            if (sql != value)
                sql = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Sql");
        }
    }
    public string SelectedText
    {
        get { return selectedText; }
        set
        {
            if (selectedText != value)
                selectedText = value;
        }
    }
    public DataTable ResultData
    {
        get { return resultData; }
        set
        {
            if (resultData != value)
                resultData = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("ResultData");
        }
    }

    public DataTable OutputData
    {
        get { return outputData; }
        set
        {
            if (outputData != value)
                outputData = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("OutputData");
        }
    }

    public string ResultStatus
    {
        get { return resultStatus; }
        set
        {
            if (resultStatus != value)
                resultStatus = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("ResultStatus");
        }
    }
    private void Row_Changed(object sender, DataRowChangeEventArgs e)
    {
        OnPropertyChanged("OutputData");
    }
    #endregion

    private List<string> sqlList()
    {
        List<string> SqlList;
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(selectedText))
            SqlList = sql.Split(';').ToList();
        else
            SqlList = selectedText.Split(';').ToList();
        return SqlList;
    }

    public async Task FormatOutput(string statement, string dateTime, string error)
    {
      statement = statement.Trim().Trim(new char[] { '\r', '\n' });
        string text = string.Empty;
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(statement) == false)
        {
            string substring = statement.ToUpper().Substring(0, statement.IndexOf(' '));
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(error) != true)
                text = error;
            else
                switch (substring)
                {
                    case ("SELECT"):
                        text = ResultData.Rows.Count.ToString() + " rows selected";
                        break;
                    case ("UPDATE"):
                        text = sqlCount + " rows updated";
                        break;
                    case ("INSERT"):
                        text = sqlCount + " rows inserted";
                        break;
                    case ("DELETE"):
                        text = sqlCount + " rows deleted";
                        break;
                    case ("DROP"):
                        text = "Table dropped";
                        break;
                    case ("CREATE"):
                        text = "Table created";
                        break;
                }
        }
        await Application.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(DispatcherPriority.Background, new Action(() =>
        {
            OutputData.Rows.Add(new object[] { dateTime, statement, text, elapsedTime });}));
    }

    public async void executeSql()
    {
        QueryRunning = true;
        foreach (string statement in sqlList())
        {
            if (cancelSql == true) { cancelSql = false; break; }
            string error = string.Empty;
            System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch sw = System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch.StartNew();
            DateTime dateTime = DateTime.Now;

            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(statement) == false)
            {
                try
                {
                    if (statement.ToUpper().Substring(0, statement.IndexOf(' ')).Contains("SELECT"))
                        ResultData = await connection.GetResultSetTask(statement);
                    else
                        sqlCount = await connection.ExecuteUpdate(statement);
                }

                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    error = ex.Message;
                }
                finally
                {
                    sw.Stop();
                    elapsedTime = sw.Elapsed.ToString(@"hh\:mm\:ss\.ffff");
                    await FormatOutput(statement, dateTime.ToString(), error);
                    cancelSql = false;
                }
            }
        }
        QueryRunning = false;
    }

    public void Cancel()
    {
        connection.cancelQuery();
        cancelSql = true;
    }
    public void Clear()
    { Sql = string.Empty; }
}
```

Comment: Glad you got it working! Note though that it's the row changed event handler that updates the UI. Using the dispatcher just shuttles the work onto the UI thread which is what the captured context on `await` will give you. In your original setup the `OutpData` setter was never hit by `OutputDat.Rows.Add` and so no event was fired. Your current solution is a way around that original problem though.

Answer (score 0):

You might have gotten this by now but: It looks as though `executeSql` does't set `OutputData` as it does with `ResultData`. The method only mutates the state of `OutputData`. In that case no event will be raised. You can simply raise the change event once you've modified `OutputData` and your ready to update the UI. Try adding this:

```
public async void executeSql()
{
        /**
        **/
        finally
        {
            OnPropertyChanged("OutputData");
            QueryRunning = false;
        }
    }
}
```

Note: you shouldn't have any issue with this command handler being async as the current context will have been captured during the await.